# Preserve custom styles using copy-paste (not via Save As or the organizer)

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, styles

I had a lengthy document with printing problems that I traced to a combination of Word page layout and printer settings. Unable to resolve the problem by changing those settings, it was pointless to use Save As to start with a new file.

So I selected all of the content and pasted it into a pristine Word document. I used paste with source formatting.

The content did, indeed, preserve the formatting but not the custom styles.

Is there something I could have done to copy-paste the formatting and custom styles to the new Word document? (I.e., without resorting to the using the styles organizer?

Using: Word 2010 on a PC

Comment: Did you try to save the custom style as a new file and make it accessible to other documents?

Comment: I do not understand your question. Are saying did I try saving the styles to a template? If yes, then my answer is no.

Comment: Would it be an option to try to save as a template?   It does not sound like a fix for your situation..   Styles in word are a PITA when you start to get fancy with formatting..